# Eclipse C++ MinGW - Can not Lauch Program <Terminated>

Tags: c++, eclipse, window, mingw

I'm a newbie in Eclipse.
I use Eclipse Indigo and MinGW to program C++. Create build a Hello word project is ok but i can run the program. It have been terminated when lanched !

This is the Build Log (Ctrl + B):

"
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Hl ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
Nothing to build for Hl

"

This is what I get when press Ctrl + F11 to run : 
"

"

[image]

anybody could tell me how to solve that problem ?

Comment: Did you choose the MinGW toolchain when creating project?

Comment: Yes, I've choosen the MinGW tool chain !

Comment: Here is a site with common problems check it out http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/ar01s05.jsp

Comment: op ! after a couple of hours finding on the Internet. I found the way to solve the problem:
You need to include the "C:\MinGW\bin" to the Path Eviroment:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xryv0fCL8us&noredirect=1

Comment: Which is one of the solutions in the article above. Nice to hear you've made it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you include C:\MinGW\bin into the path environment

In addition, make sure that you don't include paths like this -> C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
If you do so the built application will crash immediately!

Comment: Not clear. What do you mean by "Don't do it like this"? What is the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

The MinGW binaries must be in the `%PATH%`. I would not recommend to clutter the system's Path variable, unless mingw is your one and only tool chain. Instead, in Eclipse do the following:

1. open the run configuration of your executable (black arrow near the green one
2. run configurations ...
3. then select your exe
4. then go to the tab named "Environment"
5. press "New ..."
6. and add a variable named "PATH" with the content "%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin" (or wherever your MinGW is installed to)

This worked for me on Eclipse Luna in 2016.

Comment: I had the same issue and following these steps worked for me. I didn't have any environment variables set when I went into the 'environment' tab.